Sequence dates over multiple slides in PowerPoint
I am making a diary in PowerPoint that I can print. Each slide (page) has a table of 1 column and 7 rows.
I want to input the date in the first row and have it autofill the other dates down that page plus across the other slides to enable a full 12 months to be dated based on what I enter into the first row of the table.
I can use placeholder text boxes/shapes if needed as I can white the outline so it doesn't show so it doesn't have to be text input directly to the table but I cannot figure this one out.
I found VBA code to input the first date but no others so not sure if this would end up being an edit of this code or if it needs something else entirely.
Sub addDates() 
    Dim osld As Slide 
    Dim L As Long 

    Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 
    For L = 0 To 364 
        osld.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange = Format(DateAdd("d", L, #1/1/2021#), "dddd, mmmm d") 

        If L < 364 Then 
            Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, osld.CustomLayout) 
        End If 
    Next L 

End Sub



You may add code to change position and formatting of the table (oTab).

Microsoft documentation:

Slide.CustomLayout property (PowerPoint)


Slides.AddSlide method (PowerPoint)


Shapes.AddTable method (PowerPoint)

Sub addDates()
    Dim L As Long
    Dim layout As CustomLayout
    Dim oSld As Slide, oShp As Shape
    With ActivePresentation
        Set oSld = .Slides(1)
        Set layout = oSld.CustomLayout
        For L = 0 To 3  '  364,  for testing
            If .Slides.Count < L + 1 Then
                Set oSld = .Slides.AddSlide(.Slides.Count + 1, layout)
            End If
            Set oShp = oSld.Shapes.AddTable(7, 1)
            oShp.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(DateAdd("d", L, #1/1/2021#), "dddd, mmmm d")
        Next L
    End With
End Sub



That is so close to what I needed. I wanted it to have a single table with seven rows and each row dated (Mon to Sun to show a full week in a diary). Would it mean that once I edited the date in the first row of slide 1 it would update all the other slides?

Unfortunately no, it can't be automatically updated as Excel formulas after user editing. btw, it is a single table.
